# Sliding chess pieces in an Android game

Tags: android, textview, android-gridlayout

I have written a chess-like puzzle game in Android which is mostly finished. What I would like to do now is to add some graphics effects to improve the feel and look of my game, starting by improving the movements of the chess pieces.

I have structured my main game board, the chess board, as a `GridLayout` of `TextViews`, so that a chess piece is represented as a letter in a chess typeface (and a square is colored black or white by calling `setBackgroundResource` on the `TextView`). Each `TextView` has an `onClickListener`, so that when the user clicks on appropriate squares, the letters on the `TextViews` in question are changed according to chess rules. This means that the graphics feel somewhat unnatural: a chess piece which is moved disappears from its original square and immediately reappears on the square it was moved to. I would like to change this by letting the chess piece slide from its original square onto its new square. Is there any way I can do this while maintaining the GridLayout-of-TextViews logic - or will I need to change the structure of my code dramatically? In any case, if anyone knows how to get started on this, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtOne = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textone);
    txtTwo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_two);
    relative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);


    txtTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            float to_x = txtOne.getX();
            float to_y = txtOne.getY();


            float x_from = txtTwo.getX();
            float y_from = txtTwo.getY();
            //txtTwo.getLocationInWindow(fromLoc);   
            txtOne.getLocationOnScreen(toLoc);
            Animations anim = new Animations();

            Animation a = anim.fromAtoB(x_from, y_from, -to_x, -to_y, animL,1000);
            txtTwo.startAnimation(a);

        }
    });
}



public class Animations {
    public Animation fromAtoB(float fromX, float fromY, float toX, float toY, AnimationListener l, int speed){


        Animation fromAtoB = new TranslateAnimation(

                fromX, 

                toX, 

                fromY, 

                toY
                );

        fromAtoB.setDuration(speed);
        //fromAtoB.setInterpolator(new );


        if(l != null)
            fromAtoB.setAnimationListener(l);               
        return fromAtoB;
    }
}



AnimationListener animL = new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {     
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {        
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //this is just a method to delete the ImageView and hide the animation Layout until we need it again.
        //clearAnimation();       
    }
};
```

Comment: Example taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029097/android-cant-get-one-textview-to-animate-to-the-position-of-another-textview

Comment: Thank you. Right now I am trying to understand this code. What variable is "toLoc"?

Comment: That is going to be your text view that you are moving your piece to.

Comment: Okay, but how do we use it? The only place where the variable is called in the above code is in the line `txtOne.getLocationOnScreen(toLoc);` which returns a location, but we don't do seem to do anything with it. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I was also wondering: if I understand the code block correctly, what we are doing here is moving a `TextView` from one location to another, but not the text contained in the `TextView`. That would mean that the whole square is moved but not the chess piece in the square. Is this correct?

Comment: Have you found the answer for animating text? @Sid